# How install Vue on mac?

Tags: macos, vue.js, npm, error-handling, zsh

I usually work on Windows and i'm trying to install Vue desperately on my mac with all possible ways but when i check on type `Vue` or `vue --version` , i systematically receive `zsh: command not found: vue`

> All command i trying :

`npm install -g @vue/cli@latest`

`sudo npm install -g npm@latest`

`sudo npm install -g npx@latest`

`sudo npm install --global @vue/cli@latest`

`yarn global add @vue/cli`

`npm install -g @vue/cli`

I also tried to change the .zhsrc file with `/Users/mac/.zshrc` to add :

`export PATH=$PATH:/Users/mac/.npm-global/bin`

[image: screenshot of terminal]

...but still doesent work

Comment: Your screenshot shows `.bash_profile`, not `.zshrc`. Did you restart your shell after editing those files?

Comment: @tony19 yes i did with ```.zshrc``` but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globally installed Node binaries (from `npm install -g packageName`) are usually available from `/usr/local/bin`, so you should edit `.zshrc` to prefix that to the `PATH` environment variable:

```sh
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Make sure to restart your shell for it to pick up the update.